# Android - How can I add an image view dynamically?

Tags: android

I would like to add an image view dynamically and then add a 2 bitmaps to that view, how can I do this?

Comment: Well, create an instance of class ImageView, then set its source to the corresponding bitmap.  What do you mean by "2 bitmaps to that view"?

Comment: and use `LayoutInflater` to add ImageView dynamically to your layout...

Comment: You should show us what you've tried so far: getting the whole job done doesn't teach you anything...

Comment: ImageView myImageView = new ImageView(); But no luck

Comment: @JeffLemon: as you're new here I suggest you to edit your question to add your code; and if this is all you've already tried... well, you've only created an ImageView... not a great effort after all...

Answer (score 9):

I don't think you can add two bitmaps to a single image view: it sounds like you'll need to create two image views to wrap each bitmap and position them how you want the two bitmaps to be relative to each other.  Maybe surround the two ImageViews with a RelativeLayout.

Untested Pseudocode:

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

// TODO: Set attributes for layout
// i.e. RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
// layout.setLayoutParams(params);

ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(this);
imageView1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bitmap1); 

ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView(this);
imageView2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bitmap2); 

// TODO: Set LayoutParams for each imageView
// i.e. RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageParams1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(imageWidth, imageHeight); 
// imageParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
// imageParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

layout.addView(imageView1, imageParams1);
layout.addView(imageView2, imageParams2);
```